# New lvl 5 player to kit out

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, new-players, equipment

I temp geared a lvl5 orc knight with a shatterspike and a magical spiked shield from the MIC. It soaks his about 9k wealth limit, but not really what he wants (*he wanted to play an orc knight and all that entails*).
Besides the +1 full plate he got as loot, what is a good standardized (as dmg npc stock gear) for a knight. He wants to prestige as a dragonrider later, but mostly i need to get him geared well enough to survive the world long enough to gauge his preferences. I cant find a list for the phb2 classes.

To try to clarify: DMG has tables showing classes at various levels and what gear they get. I cant find one for the knight, so im asking for a generic guide like the DMG tables for that class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the table (that is more of a guide) you're looking for of suggested equipment for the Knight class at the page 218 of the Players Handbook 2.

**EDIT:**

At level 5, your budget is 9000gp; you have an extra 4700gp to spend after the suggested equipment for your class.

**PHB 2, pg. 215**

> At most levels, PCs have much higher budgets for equipment
>   than NPCs do. So when you make a player character,
>   use the NPC equipment lists as a starting point. The NPC
>   package provides the basic necessities your character needs to
>   function. From there, you can expand your character’s equipment
>   to fit his specific needs, investing the excess money in
>   better weapons or armor, or a variety of powerful, wondrous
>   items. See Table A–5: PC Remaining Budget by Level to see
>   how your PC’s wealth compares to the gear available to an
>   NPC of your level.

Comment: *FACE PALM* I never bother with appendices... I feel stupid now... Thank you.

Comment: @wolf Please note that, per page 215, “This section presents sample equipment sets **for NPCs**,” “At most levels, PCs have much higher budgets for equipment than NPCs do,” “See Table A–5: PC Remaining Budget by Level to see how your PC’s wealth compares to the gear available to an NPC of your level,” and “Character Level: 5th—Budget: 4,700 gp” Aguinaldo, you should update your answer with that.

Comment: @Aguinaldo I understand that, it was the starting point I was looking for though, and again I thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your basic go-to for magical gear, in my opinion, should always be [Ernir’s Lists of Necessary Magic Items](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items).

But before you even click that, we can get even more basic. You’re talking about 5th-level here; a lot of the stuff in that link isn’t even affordable yet. Pretty much every warrior ever is going to want these things, in more-or-less this order, before ever worrying about those lists:

- magic weapon
- magic armor
- *cloak of resistance* as big as you can get it
- enhancement bonus to the ability score you add to attack rolls, as big as you can get it
- enhancement bonus to Constitution, as big as you can get it

(A non-warrior adventurer would probably add a magic shield, probably to the detriment of the magic weapon, and the primary enhancement bonus wouldn’t be concerned with attack but rather with a casting score or something. A warrior, though, is just punished massively by system math for using a shield instead of a two-handed weapon.)

At 5th level, you can’t actually afford all of those things. So there really isn’t any need to get fancy here. A *+1 weapon*, *+1 full-plate*, *cloak of resistance +1*, and *gauntlets of ogre strength +2* is 9,950 gp (and change)—nearly a thousand gold pieces over the expected wealth of a 5th-level character.

So if the character already has a *+1 full-plate* and that’s not being counted (though really, it should be), that covers almost all of the wealth you have to worry about; you have about thousand gold pieces left. That can be handy adventuring gear, fun fluff stuff, or just cash on hand for whatever comes up.

And if we count the *+1 full-plate*, then the knight cannot quite afford the *gauntlets of ogre strength +2* yet, leaving him with a *+1 weapon*, *+1 full-plate*, a *cloak of resistance +1*, and approximately 3,400 gp. That is probably best saved up towards those *gauntlets of ogre strength +2*, but again, some of it can go towards mundane gear, fun fluff stuff, cash on hand, etc.

Contrast this with the suggested starting gear in *Player’s Handbook II* for a “cleric, fighter, knight, marshal, or paladin,” which at 5th level reads

> +1 weapon, full-plate, heavy steel shield, 500 gp

There are a number of huge problems here.

1. Gearing those classes the same is preposterous; they have some very different needs.
2. As mentioned earlier, a shield of any form is a huge problem for any warrior—of these classes, only the cleric should consider one, and that only if he’s focused solely on casting and has eschewed all martial endeavors. A two-handed weapon is a massive improvement in damage; a heavy steel shield is a paltry improvement to defenses (a +2 shield bonus to AC is very-nearly worthless).
3. There’s no *cloak of resistance*, which is just wrong; a *cloak of resistance* is an incredibly high priority for every character, and should be bought before 5th level even (and indeed, the 4th-level entry does include one).
4. It doesn’t actually cover the entirety of the character’s budget. Per page 215, these lists are “sample equipment sets **for NPCs**,” and “at most levels, PCs have much higher budgets for equipment than NPCs do. [...] See Table A–5: PC Remaining Budget by Level to see how your PC’s wealth compares to the gear available to an NPC of your level.” At 5th level, that’s **4,700 gp**. So you could start with that list—though you should drop the shield—but you still need more gear to be appropriate for a 5th-level player character. A *cloak of resistance +1* and *gauntlets of ogre strength +2* are, unsurprisingly, my suggestions for how to spend that wealth.

Comment: The knight's already got *+1 full plate*. That 2,650 gp is better spent on **either** an *amulet of tears*  **or** a *chronocharm of the horizon walker*, a *healing belt*, and an *anklet of translocation*. *Plus* a knight needs a horse, of course, of course (even if it dies a lot).

Comment: He has a horse, drawn from the kingdom's stables, and i ended up "*advising*" him to buy a shatterspike and magic spiked shield... Now with the answer up there i can "*readvise*" him on better gear that'll let him afford some important secondary items instead. Ty everyone

Comment: @wolf Updated to address the PHB2 suggestions as well; they aren’t very good (especially at higher levels, my god! at 5th level, for a knight, there are only really a couple of major problems, but those problems are serious).

Comment: @KRyan Although I agree that the PHB 2 and DMG's suggestions are no good at higher levels, he was asking for a generic guideline similar to the one at the DMG, that's why my answer.

Comment: @AguinaldoSilvestre I have no objection to your answer; it’s perfectly accurate (now). I just felt that it was worthwhile to provide a more thorough one.